# How to replace all fields with trim(field_name) for all string automatically in notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++

there is a text file containing

```
A  string,
B Date,
C  string,
D Date,
E  string,
F Date,
```

and so on...

required to replace all field with `string` as an entry with `trim(field_name)`

```
trim(A)  string,
B        Date,
trim(C)  string,
D        Date,
trim(E)  string,
F        Date,
```

...

automatically all 1000-10000 rows

Comment: why do you require notepad++? Try `sed 's/\(.*[^ ]\) *\(string,\)$/trim(\1) \2/' inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: currently I am using windows

Comment: see https://gerardnico.com/ide/notepad/replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\w+)(?=\h+string)`
- Replace with: `trim\($1\)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (\w+)         # group 1, 1 or more word character
  (?=           # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \h+           # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    string        # literally "string"
  )             # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
trim        # literally
\(          # open parens, have to be escaped in Notepad++
  $1        # content of group 1
\)          # close parens, have to be escaped in Notepad++
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]